# get the first 3 index value simultaneously from string

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have one string, where i needs to fetch first 3 number.And after some count next 3 digits like that i needs to fetch.

Here is the code:

```
let val = pref.string(forKey: "RemoteData")
print(val) //Optional("23,8,21,1,2,16,17,18,11,23,14,6,8,13,4,21,15,22,1,2,9,16,17,7,18,11,32,14,6,33,23,8,31,21,1,3,2,16,24,17,18,5")
```

I need to do some thing like this:

```
let startCount = pref.object(forKey: "startCountValue") as? Int ?? 0
let lstCount = pref.object(forKey: "LastCountValue") as? Int ?? 3
let UnlockId = arrayV[startCount..<lstCount]
```

I did this above for an array of integers. But here I don't know how can I get first 3 values from string that is:

`23,8,21` I need to do like this `let UnlockId = arrayV[startCount..<lstCount]`.

After some time I will increase the `startCount` to + 3 so next time from 4 to 6. Like that it will go.

Here the issues is `Optional("23,8,21,1,2,16,17,18,11,23,14,6,8,13,4,21,15,22,1,2,9,16,17,7,18,11,32,14,6,33,23,8,31,21,1,3,2,16,24,17,18,5")`

How I do like getting first 3 from 0 to 3. With array I did like `let UnlockId = arrayV[startCount..<lstCount]`. But in this case how can I do like same for my above values?

Updated code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let gameId = gameInfo["game_id"] as? String  // its printing correct values
    let val = pref.string(forKey: "RemoteData")!
    let arr = val.components(separatedBy:",")
    let startCount = pref.object(forKey: "startCountValue") as? Int ?? 0
    let lstCount = pref.object(forKey: "LastCountValue") as? Int ?? 3
    let unlockId = arr[startCount..<lstCount]

    if unlockId.contains(gameId!) {
        print("its locked")
    } else {
        print("its  not locked")
    }
}
```

Getting crash here: `unlockId.contains(gameId!)` but game id is not printing. It's becoming nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
let val = pref.string(forKey: "RemoteData")!
let arr = val.components(separatedBy:",")
let startCount = pref.object(forKey: "startCountValue") as? Int ?? 0
let lstCount = pref.object(forKey: "LastCountValue") as? Int ?? 3
let unlockId = arr[startCount..<lstCount]

// if you need it back to string

let unlockStr = unlockId.joined(separator:",")
```

Comment: one final issues. Getting nill value for `let gameId = gameInfo["game_id"] as? String` but its correct only.early  i use to get values

Comment: but if i change to int values is coming like this `let gameId = gameInfo["game_id"] as? Int` but here ` if unlockId.contains(String(gameId)) {` when i do i am getting error like `Cannot invoke initializer for type 'String' with an argument list of type '(Int?)'`

Comment: if i do like ` if unlockId.contains("\(gameId)") { print("its locked") { else {  print("not locked")}` if i make breakpoint for `print("its locked")` its not at all coming inside

Comment: i think that if condition is  not getting execute . So only its showing `print("not locked")`

Comment: if you get crash here `unlockId.contains(gameId!` that means `gameId` is nil , do you store it as Int or String ?

Comment: i changed to Int, and now i can able to get the value., But its not getting pass in my if condition `if unlockId.contains("\(String(describing: gameId))") { print("its locked") { else { print("not locked")} `

Comment: else breakpint only getting , eventhough the unlockId contains the gameId values. Its showing the else breakpoint

Comment: tried getting same, showing after else breakpoint. if `unlockId` contains `gameId` values also showing breakpoint of else.

Comment: can you print the values ?

Comment: this array doesn't contain 2 ?? also use gameId! to avoid optional

Comment: this is fine, other values also is there . `["23", "8", "21"]
Optional(8)`

Comment: ok do `if unlockId.contains("\(gameId!)") { print("its locked") { else { print("not locked")}`

Comment: Any help on here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55071086/showing-the-selected-data-id-values-at-first-in-collection-view

Comment: @rmaddy any help on here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55071086/showing-the-selected-data-id-values-at-first-in-collection-view

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
func testeFunc(arrayItens: String) {

    let stringArray = arrayItens.components(separatedBy: ",")

    var arrayTemp = [String]()
    var count = 0

    for item in stringArray {
        if count <= 3 {
            arrayTemp.append(item)
            count += 1
        }else{
            print(arrayTemp)
            arrayTemp.removeAll()
            count = 0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any help on here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55071086/showing-the-selected-data-id-values-at-first-in-collection-view